# Career advice with background in condensed matter physics

Tags: condensed-matter, soft-question, education

I have background in computational condensed matter physics (both BSc and MSc). But I find this field boring now. I am interested in computer simulations but not in condensed matter physics. So, for my PhD I want to change my field.

What are the alternative fields in physics that use large computations/simulations? And what is their scope in future?

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I work in the field of Optics and use computer simulations all the time.

In two different internships I've used large scale computations:

- In the simulation of laser pulse propagation, where I modeled quantum systems interacting with the laser field
- In the simulation of the optical response of complex surfaces, where I solved eigenvalue problems for specific structures.

Honestly, once you have a good knowledge in computer simulation and numerical calculations, then adapting them to different physical systems is not too hard. I even have a friend who does the same type of research I do but followed a mathematics MSc. And her thesis is on signal treatment for gravitational waves, which is not a particularly easy field, but she does just fine.

Comment: wow. very interesting!